# Manipulating json files python

Tags: python, string, json, search

I'm receiving a JSON file with a lot of information, and I'm trying to get some properties of this JSON file, I research at Python API and I couldn't find any information about some function that search at the JSON file or the strings that's loaded with the "loads" method, someone knows some way to get the specified information by a simple and clean operation?

**EDIT**

Follow the JSON file after executed the loads function:

```
{
  "servers": [
    {
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "updated": "2012-01-02T20:46:21Z",
      "hostId": "ID",
      "user_id": "ID",
      "name": "Serve",
      "links": [
        {
          "href": "URL",
          "rel": "self"
        },
        {
          "href": "URL",
          "rel": "bookmark"
        }
      ],
      "addresses": {
        "nuvemcpca": [
          {
            "version": 4,
            "addr": "10.0.0.2"
          }
        ]
      },
      "tenant_id": "nuvemcpca",
      "image": {
        "id": "15",
        "links": [
          {
            "href": "URL",
            "rel": "bookmark"
          }
        ]
      },
      "created": "2012-01-02T20:19:04Z",
      "uuid": "1710c4bb-3d48-49f9-b88e-2a19355de199",
      "accessIPv4": "",
      "accessIPv6": "",
      "key_name": "name",
      "progress": 100,
      "flavor": {
        "id": "1",
        "links": [
          {
            "href": "URL",
            "rel": "bookmark"
          }
        ]
      },
      "config_drive": "",
      "id": 15,
      "metadata": {

      }
}
```

I want to get the status information.

Comment: Did you try and use a hook function `object_hook` together with `load()`/`loads()`? Additionally, please give an example of JSON data and what you want to extract from it.

Comment: What kind of properties would you like to get? How does it look your json file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data doesn't seem to be properly formatted, in particular I don't see where's the closing square bracket for the one opening just after `"servers":`, but I'd say that what you're looking for is:

```
data['servers'][0]['status']
```

where `data` is the variable that points to the result of `json.loads`.

Comment: jcollado it works, but i've to do this to more than one json object, how can i get the count for all servers listed to do a limit condition in my loop?

Comment: @guisantogui I'm not sure about what do you mean. Could you please elaborate on this?